# Multi language wont work local running, but codepen runs fine

Tags: javascript, html, css, localization

I was researching around and found serval of options to create multi language websites, once I've implemented one method (jQuery), I've found a little bit slowness while translating and processing the information and also it worked partially in Chrome normal browser, but same exact code worked fine in CodePen.

The code I've used.

```
var arrLang = {
  "hebrew": {
    "about": "עלינו",
    "poject": "פרוייקטים",
    "service": "שירותים",
    "contact": "צור קשר",
  },
  "english": {
    "about": "About",
    "poject": "Projects",
    "service": "Services",
    "contact": "Get In Touch",
  }
};
// The default language is English
var lang = "hebrew";
// Check for localStorage support
if('localStorage' in window){

   var usrLang = localStorage.getItem('uiLang');
   if(usrLang) {
       lang = usrLang
   }

}


console.log(lang);

        $(document).ready(function() {

          $(".lang").each(function(index, element) {
            $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
          });
        });

        // get/set the selected language
        $(".translate").click(function() {
          var lang = $(this).attr("id");

          // update localStorage key
          if('localStorage' in window){
               localStorage.setItem('uiLang', lang);
               console.log( localStorage.getItem('uiLang') );
          }

          $(".lang").each(function(index, element) {
            $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr("key")]);
          });
        });
```

So far I'm getting this result:

[image]

After I click the English button, which suppose to translate the content to english, the content remains the same.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#title" class="lang" key="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section1">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">Get in Touch</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="translate" id="english">English</a>|<a href="#" class="translate" id="hebrew">עברית</a></li>
</ul>
```

The same identical code is been uploaded to [codepen](https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/gObRNev) and for some reason it works.

What can I do to solve the translation problem that wont work on chrome local run?

Comment: Can you show your header, because in code some libraries were imported did you import that too like `<script src="javascript/language.js">` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below snippet is doing what you wanted to do.

I set each element that should be effected by the language a class `lang` and a `key` attribute that contains the same key I used for the translation in the `arrLang` object.

I also set `onClick` events to the `עברית | English` links and I'm passing to the event handler function the language that should be apply, and I just set the `innerText` of each `lang` element to be the corresponding value in the selected language.

בהצלחה :D

```js
var arrLang = {
  "hebrew": {
    "about": "עלינו",
    "project": "פרוייקטים",
    "service": "שירותים",
    "contact": "צור קשר",
  },
  "english": {
    "about": "About",
    "project": "Projects",
    "service": "Services",
    "contact": "Get In Touch",
  }
};

function applyLanguage(lang) {
  let langElements = document.getElementsByClassName('lang');
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(langElements, function(element) {
    let key = element.getAttribute('key');
    element.innerText = arrLang[lang][key];
  });
}

applyLanguage('english');
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#title" class="lang" key="about">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section1" class="lang" key="project">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section2" class="lang" key="service">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#section3" class="lang" key="contact">Get in Touch</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onClick="applyLanguage('english')" class="translate" id="english">English</a>|
    <a href="#" onClick="applyLanguage('hebrew')" class="translate" id="hebrew">עברית</a></li>
</ul>
```